# Admob Interstitial error androidstudio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

i am getting this error when i want to run apk.

Error:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Öffnendes Anführungszeichen wird für Attribut "android:name" erwartet, das mit Elementtyp "uses-permission" verknüpft ist.
Error:Exception while parsing the supplied manifest file /home/murat/Downloads/BestSoccerTips/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

> Öffnendes Anführungszeichen wird für Attribut "android:name" erwartet, das mit Elementtyp "uses-permission" verknüpft ist.

my manifest.xml is like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.INTERNET”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE”/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name=”com.google.android.gms.version”
    android:value=”@integer/google_play_services_version” />

    <activity android:name=”com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity”
    android:configChanges=”keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize”
    android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.Translucent” />
    <activity android:name=".FullscreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

where is the error please help thanks

Comment: Are you sure U have written " " instead of ” ” in  <meta-data android:name=”com.google.android.gms.version”
    android:value=”@integer/google_play_services_version” />

Comment: please reCheck inverted comma you have use in first two permissions and in meta-data .

Comment: translate the error message to english, SO is not a german website.